# Using R to change a row into columns for x-number of subsequent rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set that I would like to manipulate, but I am having difficulty getting it into a user friendly format. I have the following

```
Person 1
Class        Grade
Math         A
Science      C
English      A
Person 2
Class       Grade
Math        D
English     A
Person 3
...
```

I would like to change it to the following format

```
Name       Class       Grade
Person 1   Math         A
Person 1   Science      C
Person 1   English      A
Person 2   Math         D
Person 2   English      A
Person 3
```

The issues I am having is handling it for a different number of subsequent rows for each person and also just taking a single row and making it into a column for some of the subsequent rows.

Comment: Do they literally say "Person N" or are they names?

Comment: Can you post your data in a format that mimics how it's being read in? Does it come from a csv file with blanks next to the names, an excel file, etc?

Comment: As others have said it is much easier to help when the actual data is available, but from what I can see perhaps something like `library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
colnames(df) <- c("Class", "Grade")
df %>% 
  mutate(Name = if_else(nchar(Grade) == 0, Class, NA_character_)) %>% 
  fill(Name) %>% 
  filter(Class != "Class" & Class != Name) %>% 
  select(Name, Class, Grade)`